# Python: No Module named typing and Problem with Instalation

Tags: python

I have the Problem that typing isn't installed but it is.
pip list:

```
------------------ ---------
cachetools         5.2.0
certifi            2022.9.24
charset-normalizer 2.1.1
google-auth        2.12.0
idna               3.4
pip                22.3.1
pyasn1             0.4.8
pyasn1-modules     0.2.8
requests           2.28.1
rsa                4.9
setuptools         63.2.0
six                1.16.0
typing             3.7.4.3
urllib3            1.26.12
```

But when I run the Code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Kundenkarte.py", line 4, in <module>
    from typing import List
ImportError: No module named typing
```

I also download Python 3.11 but in shell it say with python -V: Python 2.7.16;
VsCode says its in 3.10.7 and it dosn't show me problems in the code.

Comment: If you have python2 and python3 installed, try to use `python3` to invoke python3 interpreter.

Comment: Show `python -m pip list` instead

Comment: `typing` will not appear in the list of installed libraries because it belongs to the Python standard library as of Python 3.5 and later https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: @OneCricketeer it says No module named pip

Comment: @ADude Then your `pip` executable on the PATH isn't using Python2, meaning you need to run your code using `python3` (or `py3` on Windows), as suggested. You should also uninstall Python2, if possible